# Hints on Android graphics - image size

Tags: android, graphics

I'm working on my first Android project and I'm having some difficulties on deciding what could be the best image size for graphics. I have followed the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but now my problem is when actually using Adobe Illustrator and Fireworks to generate raster PNG files from vectors to export to Android.

I can't still determine the optimal PNG size for each density according to my needs. I don't have clues yet on the area that an image/icon must occupy, and I need to:

1. Generate an image of a certain size
2. Copy to Eclipse workspace
3. Preview the layout
4. Fix image size
5. Go to 1

With the unlucky result that, even if I make more resolutions of the same icon, it's too big for a Nexus S and too small for a tablet (seems they are both `xhdpi`).

Is there any plugin, tutorial or similar to help **designing** Android drawables to make them fit any actual screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Android Design Preview](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113735310430199015092/posts/fGwsV71e58Q) which allows you screen capture whatever you have in Illustrator. Also if you are having trouble converting dp to px and viceversa - I find [this converter](http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/) useful.